# How to make a deleted site collection disappear in search result?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection

I have several deleted site collections which cannot be seen in active and deleted sites in new SharePoint admin center. Attempting to browse them in the browser would return 404 File Not Found. However, when I type the names in the search bar, they appear among the results.

I have seen something like full crawl or re-index. But those are mostly for SharePoint Servers not Online and I cannot access the setting page of those sites. Is there any way to make those sites disappear from the search result?

Thanks in advance.